# Regex that works on C# doesn't work on Postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql

I was developing a RegEx to use in Posgresql using C# as a test. When I included the RegEx in a Postgresql query. It doesn't work.

Why doesn't this return rows that have "titulo" column of something like "Produto one", "Produto two" and etc. Forgive me if my mistake is a silly one but I am really lost, can't understand why it is not working.

```
select * from produto where titulo like '(?=[Produto]{6,7})P?r?o?d?u?t?o'
```

I've also tried.

```
 select * from produto where titulo like '%(?=[Produto]{6,7})P?r?o?d?u?t?o%'
```

I've defined the "titulo" column as char(100)

Comment: When using `like` you are not using a regex. Use `WHERE titulo ~  '(?=[Produto]{6,7})P?r?o?d?u?t?o'`

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) `LIKE` does not support regular expressions.

Comment: Apart from the comments above, I'm not sure your regex does what you want it to do. The square brackets `[]` define a character class and you've repeated the character `o` in that class. At most the lookahead will find 6-7 occurrences of any character(s) in that class.

Comment: so LIKE is not used for Regex. That's the first time I write a query that doesn't look for an exact string. The '%' made think that I could toss any RegEx rule as the argument for the Like Clause. I solved the problem I checked the docs.